Who should the moderators be?
One of the "The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta": who should be our moderators?

The issue of holding fair elections is largely technical. The long-term solution will likely come from us. Still, bring up these issues in meta. There is a lot of room for innovation. Discussing the criteria of a great moderator is important and picking out potential candidates is a great way to introduce outstanding contributors to your community. And we are completely open to appointing temporary Moderators when someone’s contribution makes them a standout choice for your community’s human exception handler.
For more detail see: Moderator Pro Tempore and Stack Exchange Moderator Elections Begin.

Some criteria for moderators:

excellent Italian and English skills (native Italian speaker preferred). Being a SE about the Italian language, a moderator must be able to perfectly understand the content of posts and comments, especially when dealing with flags and disputes.
patient and fair
leads by example
shows respect for their fellow users in their actions and words


Shouldn't we wait until many members of this site present themselves with great questions and great answers? The reputation threshold of 300 points is not about reputation, actually, it's about enough time for everybody to look around and to see: - is this person an active participant?

does he/she give clear, concise, structured, well argumented answers?
does he/she know what the rules are (what's on-topic, which tags are more suitable for a particular question than the others, etc.)?
is he/she calm, wise, and witty (yes, all-in-one!) not only in his/her questions and answers, but also


@I.M. we should wait until a lot of people are present to decide, but we should certainly start considering this straight away.

We have to consider the necessity of moderators. But we can't even start considering "Who?" without knowing the people. At this point, your question couldn't be about a list of specific names.

@I.M., I think we are far from proposing that list, even if I see some members that could be moderators. But, I don't know if they want to be awarded for that role.

@KyriakosKyritsis Actually, as you may see below, it's just about time to have this list. Kudos to Sklivvz, Gabriele, and Martina for taking initiative.

@KyriakosKyritsis by the way you can propose a person as a candidate. Such person will have to then accept the nomination by modifying your post.

@Gabriele, to be honest I wanted propose you and martina as moderators, so I'm a bit late. However I like Sklivvz, too, who is already an exeperienced moderator on stackexchange, but I don't know how I can describe him.

@KyriakosKyritsis just go ahead and nominate him, for the reasons you think are right. He will then be able to accept or decline the nomination and further expand his own presentation ;)

@Gabriele, I tried proposing Sklivvz, but Anna Lear, a supermod, told me that he is having some problems on Stackechange and so he cannot be awarded moderator. So I deleted my answer, c'est la vie!

@KyriakosKyritsis yep I saw that happening. I didn't know Sklivvz worked for SE :)

@GabrielePetronella The little diamond next to a user name means "moderator/SE team/someone with powers". :P

@Alenanno I somehow thought he was a pro tem pro tem moderator :D

I'll also propose myself in the same fashion.

Martina Pugliese
I'm currently working for a PhD in Physics, but I work on quantitative Linguistics: I'm interested in  understanding how language changes and evolves through time and space. This is done on the one hand through numerical simulations of interacting agents and using Corpus Linguistics for data analysis.
I tell you this because it should explain my interest in language as a whole.
Oh, I'm Italian: I was born in the North, lived there for a while, moved to the South, then moved to Rome to study and now living near it. I'm pretty convinced I have a good metalinguistic knowledge of my mother tongue and I'm fairly proficient in English. I also study other languages.
I'm sort of a recent user of Stack Exchange, something like one year ago I stumbled across the German Language beta site and I liked the philosophy of the project ever since. Then I discovered someone had opened a call for this Italian site, I committed and told people (and will continue to, now that it's a public beta).
I would love to see this site become an important point of discussion both for those who are learning our language, for those with a simple interest in it and its history, for those of us who want to share doubts and improve their knowledge. I want it to become one of the first outputs in search engine results. Let us work through this goal.
Well, that's it. I am ready to do my part towards the reaching of an improving quality of the site and managing discussions/disputes.

With the site going public, I think it's time for starting nominations. I'll go ahead and propose myself (and also a template for other nominations)

Gabriele Petronella (meta, network, Stack Overflow)
Hi! I'm Gabriele, an Italian student and I currently live in Chicago, where I'm studying Computer Science.
I've been an active user since the very first day (minute?) of beta both on the main site, mostly answering questions, and on meta, where I enjoy taking part in the definition of the identity of this very promising community!
I'm also an active Stack Overflow user and my moderator badges (Strunk & White, Copy Editor, Electorate being some examples) testify how much I care about making the SE community a better place. Obviously I'm taking care of review queues on this site too, as you can easily verify.
That being said, I think I'm a good fit for being a pro tem moderator of this site, until official elections will be held.

kiamlaluno (network profile)
I will propose myself as pro temp moderator. I am a native speaker of Italian, raised and born in Northern Italy, who learned a little of Calabrian. I think I am fluent enough in English, even though I keep using the infinitive when a native English speaker would use the gerund. :)
Being a moderator, I already know the moderator tools, and when a "not an answer" flag has been correctly used.
I am a trusted user in 3 sites, and have access to 10K moderator tools on 2 other sites.

I'm a bit surprised you haven't been selected for the mod team.
